# What are the calculations behind the properties in a re-rotated element?

Tags: css, math, rotation

I have been playing around with an idea of a contact card type of thing. Apparently hexagons are quite a new trend, but I'd like to keep it a tad simpler, namely: rotated squares. Considering I am quite knowledgeable with HTML and CSS, it wasn't that hard to accomplish this. In a few minutes I came up with [this](http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/ou445d8e/1).

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" title="Profile of Banana">
    <span style="background-image: url(http://s5.favim.com/orig/52/portrait-sigma-50mm-f1.4-hsm-canon-eos-5d-mk2-face-Favim.com-473053.jpg);">
        Queen Elizabeth
    </span>
</a>
```

**CSS**

```
a {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 50px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* Pseudo element for border */
a:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 142px;
    width: calc(100% - 8px);
    height: 142px;
    height: calc(100% - 8px);
    border: 2px solid white;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    top: 4px;
    left: 4px;
}

/* Span for bg-image and text */
a > span {
    display: block;
    height: 213px;
    width: 213px;
    top: -31px;
    left: -31px;
    position: absolute;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    padding: 76px 24px 0;
}
```

The idea is quite simple:

- Make the link itself a block element, rotated it 45 degrees. Don't forget overflow: hidden
- Rotate its child 45 degrees back, apply a background-image to this element (dynamically loaded in my case, therefore inline)

This works in all major browsers and degrades gracefully into a simple square in other browsers (IE8 and below; though you might need a [background size polyfill](https://github.com/louisremi/background-size-polyfill)). For this reason I want to keep this HTML structure.

So, what's the problem? First of all I'd like to make it applicable to different sizes where I would only need to set the width and height of the link itself (`a`) after which the height and width of its child are calculated automatically - in my project I can use the relatively new CSS3 `calc()` function, if that's of any help, along with the beauty of SASS/SCSS. In other words, I need the ratio between the width of `a` and its child `span`. As far as I can tell, it seems that the ratio is the square root of 2: `213 / 150 = 1.42`. My first question is, then, why? What's the logic and/or arithmetic behind this? Why can't the span simply take up 100% width of its parent? Why need it be exactly square root 2 times more?

Additionally, I also would like to know where the top and left values come from. I haven't figured out yet which arithmetic might be the base of is. I do know that this might be dependent on the value of `transform-origin`, but I don't know how exactly. In other words, is it possible with a pre-defined `transform-origin` value to have `top` and `left` to be zero and by doing so removing the need for a per-case calculated value? If not, how can the value of these properties be calculated based on the width value of its parent, as that's the only value that should be known?

Summary, if only the width and height of `a` are known, how do I:

- calculate the width for its child, and how can that be explained?
- calculate/use the offsets (`top` and `left`) on `span` and how can they be explained?

I do not want to use any JS solutions for this. If something isn't clear, please post a comment so I can clarify.

Comment: The diagonal of a square is sqrt(2) times the length of side (Pythagorean theorem). That effectively becomes the new "width" of the container. So to make the span fit that, just use percentages. sqrt(2) ~= 1.41, so just use `width:141%, height:141%.=`

Comment: @chiliNUT I was aware of that, but why does the width of the element change? Is the element effectively seen as a 'newly painted' element after a transformation has taken place?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question; the effective width of the rotated container is the diagonal of the square, 213px. So reasonably, the child image should be that wide to fit it. what am I missing here?

Comment: @chiliNUT In CSS the width of `a` is set to 150px. However, the effective width is 213px, as that's what setting the child to 100% result in. This is not logical. The width declared in CSS is first used, then the element is rotated, resulting in a 'new' horizontal width. In other words: declared width: 150px, actual width: 213px. My question is then, how do browsers calculate this? Do they first paint the canvas, then apply transformations and then recalculate?

Comment: weird. when I have the child set to 100%, it is effectively 150px. it expands to 213px when i set the width to 141%.

Comment: @chiliNUT My bad. I was confused and made a silly mistake. Thank you for your comments. I figured out a way to make this more widely applicable. Will post as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/ou445d8e/9)**

First of all, as the background-image defined for `span` will overlap the actual `a` element, it needs to be bigger. As we are talking about an angle of 45 degrees, this leads to a triangular cut-off shape in which the size of the main square (i.e. the image) is the long side, and the other two equally-sized lines are of the anchor. Therefore, the size of the image (`span`) should be equal to `sqrt(2)*100% ~= 141.42%`.

The positioning of the span then. First we rotate the image back by 45 degrees. Import for this action is that the `transform-origin` is set to `0 0` rather than `50% 50%`. By doing so, the element is rotated around a single point right in the top middle of the rhombus. After rotating it's only a matter of translate the element on the X-axis, which can also be done with CSS transforms: `translateX(-50%)`.

No matter what value is now passed onto `a`'s width and height, the image should always be aligned perfectly within it, with the correct dimensions.

(In the fiddle, try giving `a` a value of, say, 400px. It looks nice, doesn't it? You can also give [nice hover effects](http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/ou445d8e/13) to the image.)

```
a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    transform: rotate(45deg)  translate(50%);
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
a:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: calc(100% - 8px);
    height: calc(100% - 8px);
    border: 2px solid white;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    top: 4px;
    left: 4px;
}
a > span {
    display: block;
    height: 141.42%;
    width: 141.42%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translateX(-50%);
    transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```